# node_modules/@angular/cdk/table"' has no exported member 'CdkTextColumn'

Tags: angular

ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/text-column.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"D:/Rohan/ang_pra/my-app/node_modules/@angular/cdk/table"' has no exported member 'CdkTextColumn'.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! - you should modify your question in a proper format in order to get attention and answer from others.

Answer (score 24):

I changed the version of material to the same version of the cdk. Did the trick for me (in package.json)

```
"@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
"@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's an import link issue ... check the imported link if it's a valid one!

**this might help**

```
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
```

Please provide us the import line !